# Random 4 digit number excluding numbers 8 and 9

Tags: php

I need to generate a random 4 digit number, but exclude 8 and 9 in the generation.

Here's the code I'm using now, but it obviously doesn't exclude 8 and 9,

```
rand(pow(10, 4 - 1), pow(10, 4) - 1);
```

Comment: When you say "exclude 8 and 9" do you mean in any place? or numbers that end in 8 or 9.

Comment: So perhaps the actual requirement was "octal number"? So [`decoct()`](http://php.net/decoct) then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work as well.

```
$allowedNumbers = range(0, 7);
$digits = array_rand($allowedNumbers, 4);
$number = '';
foreach($digits as $d){
    $number .= $allowedNumbers[$d];
}

echo $number;
```

Benefit here is you can specify the allowed characters by creating an array of allowed digits. It would also allow you to include really any character from an array including letters or words.

Comment: Also nice trick with `array_rand()`! (Since `array_rand()` returns keys it could be any numerical array with any kind of data; Also OP wants 4 digits, so quickly change 3 to 4 :)

Comment: @Rizier123 yea, I forgot the key thing and fixed it. However, just by accident, this would return the same result because the call to range would have the same keys as values (since the range starts at 0 just like the keys would).

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

Here I just get the random number with [`mt_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) then I convert it to base 8 (`0-7`, means no 8 or 9) with [`base_convert()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php). And at the end I simply take the first 4 digits with [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

```
echo $number = substr(base_convert(mt_rand(), 10, 8), 0, 4);
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like?

```
$randomNumber = rand(0,7) . rand(0,7) . rand(0,7) . rand(0,7);
```